# Checked Exception Variance

Tags: java, scala, generics, variance, generic-type-argument

Java supports Checked Exceptions, but is invariant by default at the declaration site. Scala allows variance annotations using `+T` and `-T`, but does not have Checked Exceptions. I am currently designing / implementing a language that is supposed to support both, so I am wondering how variance works for checked exceptions.

***Example***:

```
interface Function[-P1, +R, E]
{
    public R apply(P1 par1) throws E
}
```

What kind of variance annotation should `E` have, or is it invariant? And further, should I generate an error if it has the opposite variance annotation, similar to how in Scala you get an error if you use a covariant type argument as a function parameter type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things like this come up *all* the time in language design, and there are issues of soundness etc., so take time to think about these issues in other aspects of the language!

But, anyway, it's up to you what it means.  Let's suppose we have

```
interface IOFunction[-P1, +R, E <: IOException] extends Function[P1,R,E]
```

and then we have a method

```
public R doIo[P1, R](f: IOFunction[P1, R, IOException]) ...
```

What if the user has their hands on a function that throws only `MyIOException <: IOException`?  Should they be able to use it?

If yes, then that's what covariance is all about.  If no, it has to be exactly IOException or nothing, then use invariance.

You can use the same reasoning for exceptions as a normal return value.  They *are* a return value of sorts, just not a normal one.

Comment: Well, it is a fun language that kind of escalated into [90k LoC](https://github.com/Clashsoft/Dyvil)... And basically everything that Java does not have. But anyway, thanks for the answer, although the last sentence would have been enough.

Comment: @Clashsoft - yes, I imagine it should be treated the same as return type.

Comment: @Clashsoft - Maybe, but then the temptation is just to copy what return values are (i.e. covariant), rather than think about the tradeoffs.